# Delete second column for selected rows from the input file in C program

Tags: c, file, file-handling

Main objective of this program:

1. Print the lines where the number in the first column lies between the start and stop values, which depend on user input. But the start and stop number should compare every first word of each line.

   For example,

   ```
   start = 770  
   stop  = 791
   ```

   It should just compare first integer of each line.
2. Delete second column of each line and add (1 or any number) at the end of each line, like example output format.

Please give me some instructions to perform this operation.

I tried to write C code, but I wasn't able to do so.  I am attaching that for your kind perusal.

#### input file format

```
766 102 1368 1369   
767 102 1369 1370   
768 102 1370 1371   
769 102 1371 1372   
770 102 1372 1373   
771 102 1373 1374  
772 102 1375 1376   
773 102 1376 1377   
774 102 1377 1378     
775 102 1378 1379   
776 102 1379 1380  
777 102 1380 1381   
778 102 1381 1382   
779 102 1382 1383  
780 102 1383 1384  
781 102 1384 1385  
782 102 1386 1387  
783 102 1387 1388  
784 102 1388 1389  
785 102 1389 1390  
786 102 1390 1391  
787 102 1391 1392  
788 102 1392 1393  
789 102 1393 1394  
790 102 1394 1395  
791 102 1395 1396  
717 204 339 1333 1341 1337  
718 204 1337 1341 1342 1338  
719 204 1338 1342 1335 355  
720 204 1333 1334 1343 1341  
721 204 1341 1343 1344 1342  
722 204 1342 1344 1336 1335
```

#### output format

```
770 1372    1373    1  
771 1373    1374    1  
772 1375    1376    1  
773 1376    1377    1  
774 1377    1378    1  
775 1378    1379    1  
776 1379    1380    1  
777 1380    1381    1  
778 1381    1382    1   
779 1382    1383    1   
780 1383    1384    1  
781 1384    1385    1    
782 1386    1387    1   
783 1387    1388    1  
784 1388    1389    1  
785 1389    1390    1  
786 1390    1391    1  
787 1391    1392    1  
788 1392    1393    1   
789 1393    1394    1  
790 1394    1395    1   
791 1395    1396    1
```

#### code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *file1;
FILE *out1;

///Function declaration
void OpenInputFile();
int Extract_SOLID_value( int To_Find_node, int To_Element_set_list);

int main()
{
    int result;
    OpenInputFile();
    int ELEMENT_SOLID;
    int STOP;
    START = 10;
    STOP = 100;

    ///Open txt file to write
    out1 = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (out1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = Extract_SOLID_value(START, STOP);
    printf("%s", result);
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(out1);
    return 0;
}/// end main

int Extract_SOLID_value( int To_Find_node, int To_Element_set_list)
{
    char line[256];
    int word;
    if (!file1) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fscanf(file1,"%s%*[^\n]",word)){
        if (word == START ){
            fgets(line, sizeof (line),file1);
            if (word == STOP){
                return;
            }
            printf("%s \n", line);
            fprintf(out1, "%s \n", line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void OpenInputFile(){

    file1 = fopen("simple_CSDexample.dat", "r");

    // check if file exists
    if (!file1){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Under what circumstances should the code add 2 to the line — you don't show any value other than 1 being added.  You almost certainly need to read whole lines using `fgets()` and then parse the lines using `sscanf()`.  If the row that started with 717 started with 777 instead, what would be the expected output?  It could easily be `717 339 1333 1341 1337 1` or `717 339 1333 1`, or it could be some other value.  At the moment, you've not fully specified the problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply, the expected output is 717 339 1333 1341 1337 1. the valve 1 should add at the end of the line.

Comment: at the end of line we can add any number (1 or 2 or etc). but the number should be same for every line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a large number of ways to approach this exercise. The primary goals, beyond basic file handling, are to recognize that you need to handle the column values both as *integers* and as *strings*. (the 1st column is the only one you need an *integer* value for).

Recognizing that your comparison will require an *integer* value, you can read the entire line, and either use `sscanf` to convert the first column to `int`, or begin *tokenizing* each column into strings immediately and convert the first to `int` using `strtol`. (either way is fine).

The larger issue is *tokenizing* the line. (the typical choice is `strtok` -- aptly named). You can also simply use a pair of pointers and "inch-worm" from the start to the end of the line, picking out columns as you go. However, for simply space or tab separated columns, `strtok` makes it easy. It is a convenient way to separate an unknown number of columns in a line, where formatted input functions would fail.

(note: there is also a `strsep` function you can use if you need to preserve columns with NULL values -- such as in a .csv file where you may have `col1,col2,,col4`)

An Implementation using `strtok` and `strtol` to perform the conversion to `int` may look something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* constants for max chars, start & stop values */
enum { BASE = 10, MAXC = 512, START = 770, STOP = 791 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";        /* line buffer */
    /* open file (or read from stdin -- default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        int val;                        /* 1st col value */
        size_t len = strlen (buf);      /* get buf len for validation */
        char *p, *delim = " \t\n";      /* pointer & delimiters */

        if (len && buf[len - 1] != '\n') { /* validate complete line */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line exceeds %d chars.\n", MAXC);
            return 1;
        }

        p = strtok (buf, delim);        /* parse 1st column (as string) */
        if (p == NULL) {                /* handle 1st col error */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: parse of first column failed.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        errno = 0;
        val = (int)strtol (p, NULL, BASE);  /* convert to long/int */
        if (errno) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: strtol() conversion failed.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        /* for each line between START & STOP (inclusive) */
        if (START <= val && val <= STOP) {

            printf ("%d", val);             /* output 1st col */

            /* tokenize line, remove 2nd column, append 1 at end */
            p = strtok (NULL, delim);       /* parse/discard 2nd column */
            if (!p) { /* handle failure to parse 2nd column */ }

            p = strtok (NULL, delim);       /* parse 3rd column */
            if (!p) { /* handle failure to parse 3rd column */ }

            while (p) {                     /* while token read */
                printf (" %-8s", p);        /* print token */
                p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* parse next token/column */
            }
            printf ("1\n");                 /* print final 1 at end */
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/parsecol <dat/columns.txt
770 1372     1373    1
771 1373     1374    1
772 1375     1376    1
773 1376     1377    1
774 1377     1378    1
775 1378     1379    1
776 1379     1380    1
777 1380     1381    1
778 1381     1382    1
779 1382     1383    1
780 1383     1384    1
781 1384     1385    1
782 1386     1387    1
783 1387     1388    1
784 1388     1389    1
785 1389     1390    1
786 1390     1391    1
787 1391     1392    1
788 1392     1393    1
789 1393     1394    1
790 1394     1395    1
791 1395     1396    1
```

A second, similar implementation using `sscanf` to convert the first column to integer (and simply re-reading the first column as a string) could look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* constants for max chars, start & stop values */
enum { MAXC = 512, START = 770, STOP = 791 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";        /* line buffer */
    /* open file (or read from stdin -- default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        int val;                        /* 1st col value */
        size_t len = strlen (buf);      /* get buf len for validation */
        char *p, *delim = " \t\n";      /* pointer & delimiters */

        if (len && buf[len - 1] != '\n') { /* validate complete line */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line exceeds %d chars.\n", MAXC);
            return 1;
        }

        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &val) != 1) { /* convert 1st col to int */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion failure column 1.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        /* for each line between START & STOP (inclusive) */
        if (START <= val && val <= STOP) {

            /* tokenize line, remove 2nd column, append 1 at end */
            p = strtok (buf, delim);        /* parse 1st column */
            if (p == NULL) {                /* handle 1st col error */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: parse of first column failed.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf ("%s", p);               /* print column 1 */

            p = strtok (NULL, delim);       /* parse/discard 2nd column */
            if (!p) { /* handle failure to parse 2nd column */ }

            p = strtok (NULL, delim);       /* parse 3rd column */
            if (!p) { /* handle failure to parse 3rd column */ }

            while (p) {                     /* while token read */
                printf (" %-8s", p);        /* print token */
                p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* parse next token/column */
            }
            printf ("1\n");                 /* print final 1 at end */
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the output is the same)

Arguably, the first is a bit more elegant, where in the second, you let `sscanf` handle the conversion and internal-validation.

Look over all the answers and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Implementation as a Function**

In response to your last comment, as `main()` itself is just a function, converting the code to a standalone function is relatively straight-forward. Traditionally, you would open/validate your file in the calling function (the one that calls the `parsecolumns` function -- `main()` in this case), and then simply pass an open `FILE*` file stream as a parameter to your function.

A quick implementation is shown below (with reasonable validation on the user input `filename`). Always, always validate all user input, and always check for `EOF` in case the user cancels input by generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> (on windoze).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* constants for max chars, start & stop values */
enum { BASE = 10, MAXC = 512, START = 770, STOP = 791 };

int parsecolumns (FILE *fp);

int main (void) {

    char filename[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    for (;;) {      /* loop until good filename provided (or canceled) */
        int rtn;    /* always capture and validate scanf return */
        printf ("enter filename: ");
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%s", filename)) != 1) {
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                fprintf (stderr, "  user canceled input.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            fp = fopen (filename, "r");
            if (!fp)    /* validate file open for reading */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed. '%s'.\n", filename);
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    if (parsecolumns (fp)) {    /* parse columns in file */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failure in parsecolumns()\n");
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}

int parsecolumns (FILE *fp)
{
    char buf[MAXC] = "";        /* line buffer */

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid file parameter 'fp'.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        int val;                        /* 1st col value */
        size_t len = strlen (buf);      /* get buf len for validation */
        char *p, *delim = " \t\n";      /* pointer & delimiters */

        if (len && buf[len - 1] != '\n') { /* validate complete line */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line exceeds %d chars.\n", MAXC);
            return 1;
        }

        p = strtok (buf, delim);        /* parse 1st column (as string) */
        if (p == NULL) {                /* handle 1st col error */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: parse of first column failed.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        errno = 0;
        val = (int)strtol (p, NULL, BASE);  /* convert to long/int */
        if (errno) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: strtol() conversion failed.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        /* for each line between START & STOP (inclusive) */
        if (START <= val && val <= STOP) {

            printf ("%d", val);             /* output 1st col */

            /* tokenize line, remove 2nd column, append 1 at end */
            p = strtok (NULL, delim);       /* parse/discard 2nd column */
            if (!p) { /* handle failure to parse 2nd column */ }

            p = strtok (NULL, delim);       /* parse 3rd column */
            if (!p) { /* handle failure to parse 3rd column */ }

            while (p) {                     /* while token read */
                printf (" %-8s", p);        /* print token */
                p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* parse next token/column */
            }
            printf ("1\n");                 /* print final 1 at end */
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i will ask if i have any question in this code.

Comment: Sure, like I said, there are *many* ways to do this. As long as you validate to catch any errors, how you do it, is largely left up to you `:)`

Comment: this operation is one of three various types of operation to perform in input file. how can i use this code in FUNCTION.

Comment: `main()` itself is nothing but a function. If you wanted to rewrite `main()` as a separate function, you would open the file before calling the function, and then just pass a `FILE*` parameter to it. Say I wanted to call the function `parsecolumns (FILE *fp)`, all you would need to do is the delete the line `FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;`. Simple. And change `return 1;` to `exit (EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: @prasath - I added an implementation as a function as an example.

Comment: @ David C. Rankin. how to delete data in the file after reading and print it in another file

Comment: You want to delete to whole input file? `unlink (filename);` (in `unistd.h`) or just truncate the file in place? (after you `fclose` the original stream) `fp = fopen (filename, "w"); fclose (fp);`

Answer (score 1):

You've given the values of `START` & `STOP` as `To_Find_node` & `To_Element_set_list` respectively to the function `Extract_SOLID_value()` so use the new names inside that function otherwise you would be getting error as `START` & `STOP` are not in the scope of that function.

You checked if the input file was created inside `OpenInputFile()` so why check again before the loop in `Extract_SOLID_value()` when nothing has changed?

You need to keep scanning the input file and write data to output file when the first value in a line is within the desired range.
A single `fgets()` won't do you got to depend on the loop like

```
int Extract_SOLID_value( int To_Find_node, int To_Element_set_list)
{
    char line[256];
    int word;
    int fword;

    while (fscanf(file1,"%d",&fword)==1){
        if (fword >= To_Find_node && fword <=To_Element_set_list ){
            fprintf(out1, "%d ", fword);
            fprintf(stdout, "%d ", fword);
            fscanf(file1, "%d", &word);
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), file1);
            line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';
            fprintf(out1, "%s 1\n", line);
            fprintf(stdout, "%s 1\n", line);
        }
        else
        {
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), file1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[`fscanf()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) will return the number values that were successfully assigned to variables.
As long as a value has been assigned to `fword` in the beginning of each iteration, the loop will go on.
Hence the condition inside the `while` loop.

We first read the first number in each line and if it is within the desired range, that number is written to output file along with the rest of the line which is obtained with `fgets()`. 
If the number is not within the desired range, we just used `fgets()` to skip that line but you can also use something like `fseek()` for the same.

`fgets()` will store the trailing new-line (`\n`) as part of the string that was read into.
So we removed it by overwriting the `\n` with the `\0` to mark end of string.

You may skip the lines with `fprintf(stdout....)`. It's equivalent to a `printf()`, I just did it to print what would be written to the file to the monitor as well.

And remember that the format specifier for an integer is `%d` and *not* `%s`.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working... but i cant able to understand completely. can you please explain.

Comment: @prasath Can you be specific? Which part?

Comment: I Dont understand, deleted second column.                                        fscanf(file1, "%d", &word);
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), file1);
            line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';
           fprintf(out1, "%s 1\n", line);

Comment: He is just reading it and doing nothing with it to "consume" the second column (move the *file position indicator* beyond the second column so the 2nd `fgets` starts reading with the 3rd column.